# Error 1324 - Contains an Invalid Character

Tags: path, sage

We are needing to do a fresh install of Sage Peachtree 2012 because the backup procedure is crashing. I run the install disc of Peachtree 2012 to do a repair, or even to uninstall and I get the following error.

**Error 1324. The path Accounting Programs contains an invalid character.**

Our Peachtree installation is running on our server in a network share: \server\Finance\Accounting Programs\Peach

I was not the original person who installed or configured this, but I have taken over the position.

We are running Windows Server 2008 x86 SP2

I need to be able to uninstall, because soon we will be doing an install of 2013. Can't get passed this error.

I have already followed advice here: http://kb.sagesoftwareonline.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14909/~/error%3A-%22error-1324%3A-the-path-to-my-pictures-contains-an-invalid-character.%22

And that is not the problem.

Are there any tricks or things I should know from people in the past that have received a similar 1324 error?  Thanks, anything at this point would be helpful.

Comment: What does the "Accounting Programs" path key in the registry contain (much like "My Pictures" in the KB article)?